# Enconding json with php and parsing

Tags: php, json, parsing

I need to create two variables to run a js with this structure

```
var sets = [{"label":"PHP","size":"6"},{"label":"SQL","size":"1"}];

var overlaps = [ {"sets":[0,1],"size":"0"}];
```

I'm trying to create it dinamically with php, like this

```
$sets[] = array("label" =>"PHP", "size" => "6");
$overlaps[] = array("sets" => array(0,1), "size" => "0");
print json_encode(array($sets, $overlaps));
```

In ajax I do this

```
$.post(action
        , {param:param}
        , function(returned_data){

            console.log(returned_data);
            var json = $.parseJSON(returned_data);
            sets = json[0];
            overlaps = json[1];
});
```

Console.log dumps this

```
[[{"label":"PHP","size":"6"},{"label":"SQL","size":"1"},{"label":"JQuery","size":"1"}],[{"sets":[0,2],"size":"1"}]]
```

The error is "**Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**"

What's wrong? How can I parse json and assign each part to the variables?

Comment: Or i'm blind, or there is no 'push' anywhere in your code?

Comment: The reason I'm here! There is no 'push'

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers Could this be a bug I jQuery's `parseJSON`?

Comment: The problem is just the assignemnt. I think the error about 'push' is from the rest of the code that need those variables. I'll comment it and keep just the assignment to try the suggestions I get

Comment: Just parsed this through my xmlHTTPRequest object with JSON.parse. Worked perfectly

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to parse it as JSON, the console insinuates that it's already an object. Also, `return` is a reserved word (language construct) in almost every language, so you should get into the habit of not using it for variable names.

```
$.post(action
    , {param:param}
    , function(return_data){
        return_data = typeof return_data=='object' ? return_data : $.parseJSON(return_data);
        //The line above parses the string only if the browser didn't already recognize it as a JSON-object.

        console.log(return_data);
        sets = return_data[0];
        overlaps = return_data[1];
   });
```

Also, you should set the header in your PHP (`$.parseJSON` certainly won't be needed then):

```
$sets[] = array("label" =>"PHP", "size" => "6");
$overlaps[] = array("sets" => array(0,1), "size" => "0");
header('Content-type: application/json'); //I added this line
echo json_encode(array($sets, $overlaps));
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange error. Could be because you are using a reserved word as a variable.

Comment: Ahn.. no I'm using 'retorno' (portuguese word for return). I will edit the question to prevent that mistake

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `$.post` already expects JSON so no need for *JSON parse*.

```
$.post(action
    , {param:param}
    , function(returned_data){

        console.log(returned_data);
        var json = returned_data;
        sets = json[0];
        overlaps = json[1];
});
```